# Sending mails automatically by console application

Tags: c#, email, console

Create one console application for sending a birthday wishing mail for company employees is here there is send mail code of only one by one employee I try but can't got a multiple emails id from database

Here Code i try it:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EmpDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connStr);
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd;
                cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT empemail,EmpDOB,empname,Photo,BdayMessage,CC FROM EmpDetails where datepart(day,EmpDOB)= datepart(day,sysdatetime()) and datepart(month,EmpDOB)=datepart(month,sysdatetime())", con);
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    ArrayList list_emails = new ArrayList();
                    int i = 0;
                    string email, Bday;
                    int diff;
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        email = reader.GetValue(i).ToString();
                        list_emails.Add(email); //Add email to a arraylist
                        i = i + 1 - 1;
                    }
                        string todaydate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM");
                        Bday = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["EmpDOB"]).ToString("dd/MM");         //date converted 
                        diff = DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Today, Convert.ToDateTime(Bday));     //compare cuurent date and date of birthday from database of emplyees with only day and month

                        //string Bday = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["EmpDOB"]).ToString("dd/MM");

                        if (diff == 0)
                        {
                            //string Email = reader["EmpEmail"].ToString();
                            string Name = reader["EmpName"].ToString();
                            string Photo = reader["Photo"].ToString();
                            string cc = reader["CC"].ToString();
                            string Bdaymessage = reader["BdayMessage"].ToString();
                            string body = "<br><b><i><font Size=4 face=Comic Sans MS color= #FF2B9E> Dear</br><br><font Size=4 face=Comic Sans MS color=#FF2B9E>" + Name + "</i></b>" + "<br>" + "<br><img src=" + Photo + "></body></html></body></html>" + "<br><b><font Size=4 face=Comic Sans MS color=#FF2B9E><i>" + Bdaymessage + "</i></b></br> " + "<br><br><br>";
                            AlternateView av = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(body, null, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);

                            LinkedResource inline = new LinkedResource(Photo, MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
                            inline.ContentId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                            av.LinkedResources.Add(inline);

                            System.Net.Mail.MailMessage msg = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();

                            msg.AlternateViews.Add(av);
                            //msg.To.Add(email);
                            msg.CC.Add(cc);
                            msg.Subject = " WIsH YoU MaNy MaNY HaPPy Birthday";
                            msg.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("example@gmail.com");
                            SmtpClient mailClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
                            NetworkCredential NetCrd = new NetworkCredential("eample@gmail.com", "password");
                            mailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                            mailClient.Credentials = NetCrd;
                            mailClient.EnableSsl = true;
                            mailClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                            mailClient.Send(msg);
                            reader.Close();
                            con.Close();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.Write("its a earlier date");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write("There is No Birthday" + ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the multiple users form the database that have birthdays with DataReader in a while loop. You just need to move the email sending code inside the loop.

Comment: So how getting multiple emails id's from database?.......when execute this code the while taking multiple emails id's form database, the count is 2 in i=i+1-1;

Comment: Actually he tries to put the retrieved email addresses into a list - the problem is accessing the right column from his DataReader: `i = i + 1 - 1;` modifying the column index surely yields not the desired output.

Comment: Ya..he is right i retrieved email  address into  ArrayList list_emails = new ArrayList();    i = i + 1 -1;  in this count is 2 after executing this code. its take 2 email address from database but after while loop jumping Bday date showing error "Invalid attempt to read when no data is present"

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to extract population report (name, birthday, hiredate, email) as excel and let [wishing application](https://github.com/mnadeem/wishing-app) take care of everything

At minimal it just need two things **excel file** with wish details (Date, name, email) and a configuration file (**application.properties**) and that is it, you are good to go.

Further there various [options to run](https://github.com/mnadeem/wishing-app/wiki/Running) the application locally (Command line, foreground, background, docker, windows scheduler, unix cron etc) Cloud.

Application is [highly configurable](https://github.com/mnadeem/wishing-app/wiki/Configurations-unleashed) , you can configure various details like:

- Workbook loading options
- Image options to send with wishes.
- SMTP Configurations
- Other application level configurations like, when to send wish, belated wish, logging etc.

  **Disclaimer** : I am the owner of the application